# Return 0 for a month where there is no data in a postgreSQL query

Tags: sql, postgresql

this is my query :

```
    SELECT  
        "Date" as "Date",
        max("Nombre d'événements") as "Number of events"
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT  
            MAX(event.creation_date) as creation_date,
            event."Date" as "Date", 
            (count(distinct event_resources.user_id) + count(event_resources.native_resource_id)) as "Number of events"
        FROM 
        ( 
            SELECT  
                id as id, 
                date(event.creation_date) as creation_date, 
                to_char(event.creation_date,'MM-YYYY') as "Date"
            FROM event
        ) as event, event_resources
        WHERE event.id = event_resources.event_id 
        GROUP BY  "Date"
    ) as tmp
    GROUP BY  "Date"
    ORDER BY min(creation_date) asc ;
```

this is what is currently returns :

```
| Date      | Number of events
| --------- | ---------------
| 12-2019   | 1
| 02-2020   | 1
| 03-2020   | 5
| 05-2020   | 5
| 06-2020   | 4
| 07-2020   | 8
```

i would like to be able to visualize the months with no data (no event) in the returned table with the value 0 as the Number of events.

Desired output

```
| Date      | Number of events
| --------- | ---------------
| 12-2019   | 1
| 01-2020   | 0
| 02-2020   | 1
| 03-2020   | 5
| 04-2020   | 0
| 05-2020   | 5
| 06-2020   | 4
| 07-2020   | 8
```

anyone can help ? have a great day

*Edit - this is the solution obtained with the help of the comments ;)*

```
with q as (
    SELECT  
        "Date" as "Date",
        max("Number of events") as nombre
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT 
            event."Date" as "Date", 
            (count(distinct event_resources.user_id) + count(event_resources.native_resource_id)) as "Number of events"
        FROM 
        ( 
            SELECT  
                id as id,
                to_char(event.creation_date,'MM-YYYY') as "Date"
            FROM event
        ) as event, event_resources
        WHERE event.id = event_resources.event_id 
        GROUP BY  "Date"
    ) as tmp
    GROUP BY  "Date"
)
select to_char(gs.yyyymm, 'MM-YYYY') as month, q.nombre
from 
(
    select max(event.creation_date) as max_date, min(event.creation_date) as min_date
    from event
) as tmp, generate_series(min_date, max_date, interval '1 month') gs(yyyymm) 
left join q
        on q."Date" = to_char(gs.yyyymm, 'MM-YYYY')
group by month, nombre
order by min(gs.yyyymm) asc;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can probably simplify your query, but without sample data and desired results, it is hard to give specific details.  In the mean-time, though, you can just use `generate_series()` and `left join`:

```
with q as (
      < your query here without the order by >
     )
select gs.yyyymm, q."Number of Events"
from generate_series('2019-12-01'::date, '2020-07-01'::date, interval '1 month') gs(yyyymm) left join
     q
     on q."Date" = to_char(gs.yyyymm, 'MM-YYYY')
order by gs.yyyymm;
```

Comment: thank you for your answer
i apologize, i really can't provide sample data... but just below "desired output" you can see which results i want
i saw this possibility (with ```generates_series()```) in another post, but i don't want my query to be static in time... any other lead ?

Comment: Use a subquery that gets you the minimum and maximum values rather than hard coding them.

Comment: thank you @LaurenzAlbe, i think i can work with that!